# What causes garbled text in Chrome URL text field?

Tags: google-chrome, graphics

This is what I see in the URL bar of Google Chrome (Version 31.0.1650.57 m):

[image: Garbled text]

But copying and pasting this text shows:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered
```

Why is this?

<sub>**Note:** Rebooting solves this issue. My question is *why* it happens on occasion and requires a reboot?</sub>

Comment: Clear os/browser bug. My first tip were, that one of the multilang databases is broken. Try to change the chrome gui to another language, what happens? If this doesn't go, reinstall chrome.

Comment: Just closing and reopening Chrome resolves the issue, no language change needed. The translation theory is interesting. It does change font like Notepad font.